# Matrix error before and after upgrade

Tags: matrix

I'm having an issue with Matrix where after upgrading from Matrix 2.4.3 to 2.5.3 I get this error on every page of the site regardless of the content on the page. Any ideas on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

```
Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'is_draft' in 'where clause'

SELECT row_id, col_id_1, col_id_2, col_id_3 FROM exp_matrix_data WHERE field_id = 17 AND entry_id = 1048 AND is_draft = 0 ORDER BY row_order ASC LIMIT 1

Filename: third_party/matrix/ft.matrix.php

Line Number: 2808
```

Site specifications

- EE 2.5.3
- PHP Version 5.3.20
- SQL 5.0.77

Plugins

- Structure
- Matrix
- WYGWAM
- Playa
- Assets

Comment: Try Ian's suggestion below - if that doesn't fix it, please email super admin details via support@pixelandtonic.com and we can get you fixed up.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It sounds like Matrix may not have completed it's update routine. Did you go to Add-Ons → Fieldtypes → Matrix to trigger the update script?

Comment: Didn't realize that was part of upgrading instructions, as a fieldtype. Yeah that fixed it. Thank you.

Comment: No worries. It can be easy to forget.

Comment: Actually it's on triggering the update script by method mentioned that I got the error. Something more is afoot here, I think...